# Cut everything before and after a string from the PS command Get-ADUser

Tags: string, powershell

```
   $test= Get-ADUser -Server dc1 hpeter -Properties DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

Output is something like this:

```
 CN=Hans Peter,OU=NRH,OU=Stuttgart,OU=XXXX,OU=XXXX,OU=XXXX,DC=DE,DC=Richard-Mayer,DC=org
```

How can I cut everything before and after the first DC String *"DC=DE"* so that I only get the first `DC=DE` entry?
I tried with the `split()` but hadn't success. Do I must convert the Output to a String with the `ToString()` that I can use the split method?
For any help I would be very grateful.

Comment: Beware that it is legal to have a comma in some DN fields. It should be escaped by a backslash so any string manipulation should handle that.

Comment: Something like this: `((Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName -split ',')[0]`

Comment: Aren't you actually looking for the first part of the distinguished name of the _domain_ of the user?

Comment: @Olaf, yes, your sample gives me the second part.

Comment: Oooops ... my mistake. The account youR'e looking for is in a child domain, right?  So forget about my comment. Sorry for bothering. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the delimiter `,` for `split()` method:

```
$test= Get-ADUser -Server dc1 hpeter -Properties DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$arr = $test.Split(',')
```

Then filter and select the first one:

```
$result = $arr | Where-Object {$_ -like "DC=*"} | Select-Object -First 1
```

#### Some possible improvements:

You might also explicitly convert to `String` using:

```
[string]$test= Get-ADUser -Server dc1 hpeter -Properties DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

`DistinguishedName` can be accessed like this:

```
[string]$test = (Get-ADUser -Server dc1 hpeter -Properties DistinguishedName).DistinguishedName
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. Here is one:

```
$string = 'CN=Hans Peter,OU=NRH,OU=Stuttgart,OU=XXXX,OU=XXXX,OU=XXXX,DC=DE,DC=Richard-Mayer,DC=org'
$dc = $string.Split(',')[6]
```

Comment: this solution is easier, nice.

Comment: Would be worth to use `[-3]` instead of `[6]` in case the depth of user account location is not static (there's a bigger change that `DC` part is more or less similar).

Comment: This assumes the location of the DC=DE. It will not work for a user that exists in an OU on a different level.

Comment: It also assumes that the OP knows their environment and will tailor this example to fit it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others have said, you could use the split method in a manner similar to this:

```
$test= Get-ADUser -Server dc1 hpeter -Properties DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty @{name="DC";expression={($_.DistinguishedName -split ",OU=")[6]}}
```

Comment: I don't get an Output for this.

Comment: My apologies. Remove the -expandproperty.